# jTDS Connect URL

Tags: database-connection, jtds

I am using jTDS to connect SQL Server 2005 Express. My connect url is `jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433/dbstore;user=myusername,password=mypassword`

It's not connecting with a "SQL server refusing connection" problem.

Is there something wrong with my code.

Comment: This is a simple and valid question, do not understand why is it closed...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your connection string is incorrect. The user and password parameters should be separated with a ";" instead of ","

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433/dbstore;user=myusername;password=mypassword
```

Also, there are numerous other questions about jTDS connection strings such as:

[Help me create a jTDS connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862283/help-me-create-a-jtds-connection-string)

Please search before creating a new question.