# Hibernate MS SQL connection

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I am connecting to MS SQL via hibernate using the jar jtds-1.3.0.jar and below is the configuration file

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/login</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.username">sa</property>
    <property name="connection.password">user</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>


    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->

        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <!--  Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <!-- configuration pool via c3p0--> 
    <property name="c3p0.acquire_increment">5</property> 
    <property name="c3p0.idle_test_period">100</property> <!-- seconds --> 
    <property name="c3p0.max_size">20</property> 
    <property name="c3p0.max_statements">50</property> 
    <property name="c3p0.min_size">5</property> 
    <property name="c3p0.timeout">1800</property> <!-- seconds --> 
    <property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
    <!--Basic user functionality-->

</session-factory>
```

but every time i run my project its giving error as Network error and connection refused.
I refereed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497725/connecting-to-ms-sql-through-hibernate) for the still giving errors. Below is my stack trace

```
java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:434)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:183)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:134)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:183)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:172)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:152)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1074)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1061)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1796)
at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:635) Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.createSocketForJDBC3(SharedSocket.java:300)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.<init>(SharedSocket.java:253)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:329)
```

below is the image 
[image: Server Configuration Manager]
can anyone tell me where i am going wrong.

Comment: use the port number to make the connection : default port number is 1433 , this is one of the cause of Connecion refused IOException

Comment: Is your schema really called "login"?

Comment: yes my schema is login

Comment: @theunlucky Hi that port number is optional right???

Comment: @Rithesh , right .. i suspect that u may have chance of using incorrect username & password  please verify it  , can u update the Stack trace here..

Comment: @theunlucky i am getting same exceptions after cross checking username & pass, and by putting the port number and increasing the pool size by 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure that your server is listening on port 1433? To confirm that the actual problem is with Java (i.e. your configuration) run

```
telnet localhost 1433
```

If you get no answer then MS SQL is most likely not running on 1433. There is an option to use dynamic ports in MS SQL, make sure you didn't enable that.

http://frightanic.com/software-development/connecting-to-ms-sql-server-2012-express-through-jdbc-failed/:

> The first hurdle was to learn that MS SQL Express by default uses
>   dynamic ports. To connect in a TCP/IP fashion from Java you need to
>   configure static ports manually.

Comment: Hi Marcel, i created db in Microsoft SQL server Management Studio does it make any difference??

Comment: Hi @Marcel Stor need to run telnet localhost 1433 in command prompt or ?

Comment: @Rithesh, I don't know. Did you read the post I linked and the Microsoft article it points to (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177440.aspx)?

Comment: yes i read that also gone through also with [this](http://knowhow.visual-paradigm.com/hibernate/solving-sql-server-connection-problem/) link but nothing worked

Comment: @Rithesh, you still haven't reported whether connecting with telnet works and if you're using dynamic or static ports.

Comment: Hi @MarcelStör i have updated the image there was no 0 in dynamic ports

Answer (score 2):

Yes `portNumber` is Optional . The default is 1433. If you are using the `default`, you do not have to specify the `port`, nor its preceding ':', in the `URL`.

```
<property name="connection.pool_size">10</property>
```

It will allow only one connection at a time .I guess some where in your program  you are trying to open another session .

Have  a look on

[Hibernate config connection pool size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802684/hibernate-config-connection-pool-size)

Comment: hi suresh ya i have given the port number and increased the pool size to 10. but still i think there is problem in connecting to SQL Server

Comment: Is everything fine like this link http://knowhow.visual-paradigm.com/hibernate/solving-sql-server-connection-problem/

Comment: Hi suresh i have gone through that link, enabled the telnet was not connecting to server then changed the security to SQL Server Authentication still the same result.

Comment: Even though its optional give port as 1433 and try once.

Comment: And make sure SQL Server Browser service needs to be running (in Services).

Comment: And one more thing you have to restart the SQL browser after enable the TCP/IP property

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24364/discussion-between-rithesh-and-the-suresh-atta)

Answer (score 2):

try changing the url to:

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1443;DatabaseName=login</property>
```

separating the schema name from the server address.

I use DBVisualizer to connect to MS Sql and it show the format of the url config:

```
URL Format: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<server>:<port1443>;DatabaseName=<database>
```

Comment: He did that already, read the other answers and his comments.

Comment: the point here was to separate the server address from the schema name adding "DatabaseName=login" to the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I found the my solution to the problem. I changed my port number from 1433 to 1434 which was active by referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13231606/jdbcjtds-connection-to-sql-server) discussion. Thank you all for your time