# Connect to SQL 2008 from Java 1.4

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I have Java code that, for the time being, has to be run in Java 1.4 and is using the *SQL Server 2000 Driver for JDBC*.  One of the MS SQL Servers we work with is being upgraded from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2008.  The SQL 2000 JDBC driver does not work with 2008, as I've found out in practice and from [reading online](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/sqldataaccess/thread/c91f0a42-847c-4fb6-8939-264b517bf1e7).

All (?) newer versions of JDBC that support SQL 2008 (2, 3 & 4) [require](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2505) Java 5 or Java 6.

How can I connect to MS SQL Server 2008 from Java 1.4?

**Edit** It looks like *SQL Server 2005 JDBC Driver 1.2* will allow me to connect to SQL 2008 from Java 1.4, but that **[the download isn't available anymore](http://news.softpedia.com/news/SQL-Server-JDBC-Driver-1-2-Downloads-to-Be-Discontinued-137129.shtml)**??

Comment: Why do you have to use Java 1.4? Why can't you update to a version that will work with the newer JDBC drivers?

Comment: @Nexion - My code is run inside of IBM Maximo 6, which requires Java 1.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a third party driver like jdts: http://jtds.sourceforge.net. The 1.2.x versions run on versions 1.3 to 6. Here's a good link which describes how to use it: [Help me create a jTDS connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862283/help-me-create-a-jtds-connection-string).

Comment: If I'm reading their page correctly, I would make sure the jar is accessible in my classpath and then modify my existing static variables that store the MSSQL JDBC settings ("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver" and "jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://").  Sound about right?

Comment: Yes. I added a link describing in detail how to use it above.