# How to find the IP address and Port Number for SQLSERVER 2008 to connect database from java

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to connect my SQLSERVER 2008 (localhost)database with java.

I m using net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver and I have all connection properities without IP address and portnumber.

```
class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1098/userdb" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
```

Comment: SO is the wrong site for questions like this; you may want to try http://serverfault.com/ instead.

Comment: Not really a question for serverfault - this is very definitely a question that ought to be handled internally - you really don't want a coder who has no idea how to access his database. Internal documentation should handle this. Please do not punt this over to SF or SU.

Comment: The answer from ServerFault will be "ask the system administrator".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> localhost is your ip number 127.0.0.1

and default port should be 1433

Normally the connection string is like:

jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=XXX;user=AAA;Password=BBB

See links that might show you the different steps:

[Help me create a jTDS connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862283/help-me-create-a-jtds-connection-string)

http://forums.devshed.com/ms-sql-development-95/jdbc-and-sql-server-2008t-579217.html

http://thusithamabotuwana.wordpress.com/2012/01/08/connecting-to-sql-server-using-jtds/

Comment: i given this but it was not connect to database

Comment: sorry,the given url(jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=XXX;user=AAA;Password=BBB)is also not working

Comment: This is a sample connection string. You did replace the XXX, AAA and BBB I hope... check the links in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, it works for this url:String Connectionurl = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433/userdb";