# can't generate java from command line: org.jooq.exception.DetachedException: Cannot execute query. No Connection configured

Tags: java, code-generation, jooq

I tried to generate JOOQ Java code from my database.

When i execute

```
java -cp "bla.xml;jooq-3.5.0.jar;jooq-meta-3.5.0.jar;jooq-codegen-3.5.0.jar;jtds.jar" org.jooq.util.GenerationTool bla.xml
```

i get:

```
org.jooq.exception.DetachedException: Cannot execute query. No Connection configured
        at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:303)
```

I have no clue why it does not generate java code.
The Startup says:

```
Dez 03, 2014 11:43:33 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Information: Initialising properties  : bla.xml
Dez 03, 2014 11:43:33 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger warn
Warnung: DEPRECATED               : The configuration property /configuration/generator/database/dateAsTimestamp is deprecated as it is superseded by custom bindings and converters. It will thus be removed in the future.
Dez 03, 2014 11:43:33 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Information: License parameters
Dez 03, 2014 11:43:33 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Information: ----------------------------------------------------------
Dez 03, 2014 11:43:33 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Information:   Thank you for using jOOQ and jOOQ's code generator
Dez 03, 2014 11:43:33 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Information:
Dez 03, 2014 11:43:33 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Information: Database parameters
Dez 03, 2014 11:43:33 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Information: ----------------------------------------------------------
Dez 03, 2014 11:43:34 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Information:   dialect                : SQLSERVER
Dez 03, 2014 11:43:34 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Information:   URL                    :
Dez 03, 2014 11:43:34 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Information:   target dir             : C:/Users/x/Downloads/jOOQ-3.5.0/jOOQ-lib/src
Dez 03, 2014 11:43:34 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Information:   target package         : de.xy.model.database
Dez 03, 2014 11:43:34 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Information:   includes               : [.*]
Dez 03, 2014 11:43:34 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Information:   excludes               : []
Dez 03, 2014 11:43:34 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Information:   includeExcludeColumns  : false
Dez 03, 2014 11:43:34 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Information: ----------------------------------------------------------
Dez 03, 2014 11:43:34 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Information:
Dez 03, 2014 11:43:34 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Information: DefaultGenerator parameters
Dez 03, 2014 11:43:34 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Information: ----------------------------------------------------------
Dez 03, 2014 11:43:34 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Information:   strategy               : class org.jooq.util.DefaultGeneratorStrategy
Dez 03, 2014 11:43:34 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Information:   deprecated             : true
Dez 03, 2014 11:43:34 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Information:   generated annotation   : true
Dez 03, 2014 11:43:34 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Information:   JPA annotations        : false
Dez 03, 2014 11:43:34 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Information:   validation annotations : false
Dez 03, 2014 11:43:34 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Information:   instance fields        : true
Dez 03, 2014 11:43:34 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Information:   records                : true
Dez 03, 2014 11:43:34 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Information:   pojos                  : false
Dez 03, 2014 11:43:34 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Information:   immutable pojos        : false
Dez 03, 2014 11:43:34 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Information:   interfaces             : false
Dez 03, 2014 11:43:34 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Information:   daos                   : false
Dez 03, 2014 11:43:34 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Information:   relations              : true
Dez 03, 2014 11:43:34 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Information:   global references      : true
Dez 03, 2014 11:43:34 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Information: ----------------------------------------------------------
Dez 03, 2014 11:43:34 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Information:
Dez 03, 2014 11:43:34 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Information: Generation remarks
Dez 03, 2014 11:43:34 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Information: ----------------------------------------------------------
Dez 03, 2014 11:43:34 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Information:   none
Dez 03, 2014 11:43:34 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Information:
Dez 03, 2014 11:43:34 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Information: ----------------------------------------------------------
Dez 03, 2014 11:43:34 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Information:
```

The bla.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<configuration>
  <!-- Configure the database connection here -->
  <jdbc>
    <driver>net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</driver>
    <url>jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=x</url>


    <!-- You can also pass user/password and other JDBC properties in the optional properties tag: -->
     <properties>
      <property><key>user</key><value>x</value></property>
      <property><key>password</key><value>x</value></property>
    </properties>
  </jdbc>

  <generator>
    <database>
      <!-- The database dialect from jooq-meta. Available dialects are
           named org.util.[database].[database]Database.

           Natively supported values are:

               org.jooq.util.ase.ASEDatabase
               org.jooq.util.cubrid.CUBRIDDatabase
               org.jooq.util.db2.DB2Database
               org.jooq.util.derby.DerbyDatabase
               org.jooq.util.firebird.FirebirdDatabase
               org.jooq.util.h2.H2Database
               org.jooq.util.hsqldb.HSQLDBDatabase
               org.jooq.util.informix.InformixDatabase
               org.jooq.util.ingres.IngresDatabase
               org.jooq.util.mariadb.MariaDBDatabase
               org.jooq.util.mysql.MySQLDatabase
               org.jooq.util.oracle.OracleDatabase
               org.jooq.util.postgres.PostgresDatabase
               org.jooq.util.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaes
               org.jooq.util.sqlserver.SQLServerDatabase
               org.jooq.util.sybase.SybaseDatabase

           This value can be used to reverse-engineer generic JDBC DatabaseMetaData (e.g. for MS Access)

               org.jooq.util.jdbc.JDBCDatabase

           This value can be used to reverse-engineer standard jOOQ-meta XML formats

               org.jooq.util.xml.XMLDatabase

           You can also provide your own org.jooq.util.Database implementation
           here, if your database is currently not supported -->
      <name>org.jooq.util.sqlserver.SQLServerDatabase</name>

      <!-- All elements that are generated from your schema (A Java regular expression.
           Use the pipe to separate several expressions) Watch out for
           case-sensitivity. Depending on your database, this might be
           important!

           You can create case-insensitive regular expressions using this syntax: (?i:expr)

           Whitespace is ignored and comments are possible.
           -->
      <includes>.*</includes>

      <!-- All elements that are excluded from your schema (A Java regular expression.
           Use the pipe to separate several expressions). Excludes match before
           includes -->
      <excludes>
  <!--         UNUSED_TABLE                # This table (unqualified name) should not be generated
         | PREFIX_.*                   # Objects with a given prefix should not be generated
         | SECRET_SCHEMA/.SECRET_TABLE # This table (qualified name) should not be generated
         | SECRET_ROUTINE              # This routine (unqualified name) ...
         -->
      </excludes>

      <!-- The schema that is used locally as a source for meta information.
           This could be your development schema or the production schema, etc
           This cannot be combined with the schemata element.

           If left empty, jOOQ will generate all available schemata. See the
           manual's next section to learn how to generate several schemata -->
      <inputSchema>dbo</inputSchema>
    </database>

    <generate>
      <!-- Generation flags: See advanced configuration properties -->
    </generate>

    <target>
      <!-- The destination package of your generated classes (within the
           destination directory)

           jOOQ may append the schema name to this package if generating multiple schemas,
           e.g. org.jooq.your.packagename.schema1
                org.jooq.your.packagename.schema2 -->
      <packageName>de.x.model.database</packageName>

      <!-- The destination directory of your generated classes -->
      <directory>C:/Users/athom/Downloads/jOOQ-3.5.0/jOOQ-lib/src</directory>
    </target>
  </generator>
</configuration>
```

Comment: can you show the codegen configuration (bla.xml) that you are using? Have you properly defined the jdbc section as in [this example](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.5/manual/code-generation/codegen-configuration/)?

Comment: Updated the Question. I used that example.

Comment: Your command-line call looks good to me. Is the exception you've encountered the first exception? What is its full stack trace? Also, are you sure your connection string is correct? If you're using jtds (instead of the commercial SQL Server JDBC driver), [I suspect you should have something with `jtds` in it...?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1862508/521799)

Comment: The jtds url was the problem. You could put your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using jTDS as a driver implementation, but a SQL Server JDBC driver URL:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=x
```

The jTDS connection URL format is slightly different. Essentially, you're missing the `jtds:` prefix, and the database name is prefixed by a `/`:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/x
```

More information can be seen here:

- http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html#urlFormat
- [Help me create a jTDS connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862283/help-me-create-a-jtds-connection-string/1862508#1862508)