# Unable To Create a jTDS Connection to SQL Server 2012

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, connection-string, jtds

I'm attempting to create a jTDS connection string in order to connect my application to a SQL database and I've used the following as a reference:

[Help me create a jTDS connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862283/help-me-create-a-jtds-connection-string)

I've been able to create/concatenate my connection string as follows - however I continuously get errors and I am unable to connect. It appears the string is created properly - so I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong or where exactly the point of failure is.

Any tips/suggestions/answers are greatly appreciated.

jTDS connection string 1:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://OFFICE1XX:1433/FingerPrint;instance=mssql12;user=username;password=password;
```

Result:

```
05-12 13:57:27.470: E/ERROR CONN 1 Class(24610): Unknown server host name 'Host is unresolved: OFFICE1XX'.
```

jTDS connection string 2:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.1XX.X.X0:1433/FingerPrint;instance=mssql12;user=username;password=password;
```

Result:

```
05-12 13:59:37.750: E/ERROR CONN 1 Class(24980): Network error IOException: failed to connect to /192.1XX.X.X0 (port 1433): connect failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
```