# Annoying JDBC - MySQL error " FATAL EXCEPTION in createStatment call", How to solve this?

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc, import

When I run the emulator, it woks perfectly with no errors, but when I press the Login button, I get error "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method".

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button add;
    TextView errorlbl;
    EditText name, address, pincode;
    Connection connect;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
    Statement st;
    String ipaddress, db, username, password;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private Connection ConnectionHelper(String user, String password,
                                        String database, String server) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Connection connection = null;
        String ConnectionURL = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            ConnectionURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + server + ";"
                    + "databaseName=" + database + ";user=" + user
                    + ";password=" + password + ";";
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionURL);
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            Log.e("ERRO", se.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
        }
        return connection;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnadd);

        errorlbl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblerror);

        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtname);
        address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtaddress);
        pincode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtpincode);

        ipaddress = "92.244.93.250:3306";
        db = "lokal";
        username = "lokal";
        password = "12lokal34";
        connect = ConnectionHelper(username, password, db, ipaddress);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    st = connect.createStatement();

                    preparedStatement = connect
                            .prepareStatement("insert into studentRecord(Name,Address,Pincode) values ('"
                                    + name.getText().toString()
                                    + "','"
                                    + address.getText().toString()
                                    + "','"
                                    + pincode.getText().toString() + "')");
                    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                    errorlbl.setText("Data Added successfully");
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    errorlbl.setText(e.getMessage().toString());
                }

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Logcat error says:

> 2182-2182/app.mysqlapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: app.mysqlapp, PID: 2182
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.sql.Statement java.sql.Connection.createStatement()' on a null object reference

Comment: Do you have the full stacktrace?

Comment: The connection object seems to be null. Are there any errors from the `ConnectionHelper` call?

Comment: It looks like your `ConnectionHelper` is returning `null`. Are you logging any errors?

Comment: the simplest way to fix it is: **do not use JDBC on android platform**

Comment: But what if I want to create an Android App, which Login form will connect to MYSQL database ?

Comment: You aren't connecting to MySQL, but Microsoft SQL Server instead. Why tag and mention MySQL?

Comment: Instead of using Microsoft SQL I'd use MySQL on the ip: 92.244.93.250:3306 using JDBC. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its clear from your code that there is something wrong going in your **ConnectionHelper**  its giving back null

**Note :its my guess only**

**you have used net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver and thats for MsSql server and you have given 3306 as port of db server, mostly 3306 is used for MySql, so are you sure you have configured your MsSql on 3306**

Comment: That was the problem thank you mate!:))

Comment: @Erzi it's my pleasure

Answer (score 1):

Your `ConnectionHelper` method traps exceptions and instead returns `null` when something goes wrong. So when calling it, since you've opted out of structured exception handling, you have to allow for a `null` return value. You're not doing that, you're just using the return value of `ConnectionHelper` without checking whether it's `null` first.

Clearly, an error is occurring in `ConnectionHelper`, which you're trapping and dumping to the log. So that will tell you what's going wrong.

---

Side note: The **overwhelming** convention in Java is **not** to capitalize the first letter of methods.

Side note 2: It would be **much better practice** to allow the exceptions in `ConnectionHelper` to propagate to your top level entry point and handle them there.

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that your connection object is null which means ConnectionHelper() is returning null.. Which further implies that below line is returning null

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionURL);
```

Now this can only happen when either driver name is wrong or ConnectionURL is wrong. Since driver name seems correct the only place of error is your connection url string. I just checked this similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1862508/720176) at SO.

To me it looks like, Connetion URl string should be

```
 ConnectionURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + server + ";"
                    + "database=" + database + ";user=" + user
                    + ";password=" + password + ";";
```

Note the difference in `database` and `databaseName` variable in connection String. This should work.

**UPDATE** All the points mentioned in @T.J. Crowder's answer is correct and you should make a habit of following standard conventions.